# Why CreateCompatibleBitmap() isn't compatible with CreateCompatibleDC()

Tags: winapi

I created a small program that should take a screenshot. I want to understand line 11:

```c
HBITMAP hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcmem, w, h);
```

If I call `CreateCompatibleBitmap` with the desktop DC, it works well; but, if I put `hdcmem` as the first argument, it goes wrong: The buffer ends up being empty. Why is that so if `hdcmem` is compatible with desktop DC?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    UINT w = 100;
    UINT h = 100;
    UINT bitsPerPix = 24;
    UINT buffSize = (w * bitsPerPix + 31) / 32 * 4 * h;
    HDC desktop = GetDC(0);
    HDC hdcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(desktop);
    HBITMAP hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcmem, w, h);
    hbm = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcmem, hbm);
    BitBlt(hdcmem, 0, 0, w, h, desktop, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    hbm = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcmem, hbm);
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmf{};
    bmf.bfType = 0x4d42;
    bmf.bfOffBits = sizeof BITMAPFILEHEADER + sizeof BITMAPINFOHEADER;
    bmf.bfSize = sizeof BITMAPFILEHEADER + sizeof BITMAPINFOHEADER + buffSize;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi{};
    bmi.biSize = sizeof bmi;
    bmi.biWidth = w;
    bmi.biHeight = h;
    bmi.biBitCount = bitsPerPix;
    bmi.biCompression = 0;
    bmi.biPlanes = 1;
    char* buff = new char[buffSize];
    GetDIBits(hdcmem, hbm, 0, h, buff, (LPBITMAPINFO)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    std::ofstream ofile("D:\\test.bmp", std::ios_base::binary);
    ofile.write((char*)&bmf, sizeof bmf);
    ofile.write((char*)&bmi, sizeof bmi);
    ofile.write(buff, buffSize);
    ofile.close();
    delete[] buff;
    DeleteObject(hbm);
    DeleteDC(hdcmem);
    ReleaseDC(0, desktop);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CreateCompatibleBitmap` function creates a bitmap that is compatible with the **physical device** that is associated with the device context passed as its first argument. A memory device context does not have such an associated physical device, so what will that bitmap be compatible with? Probably, though not *explicitly* documented, it will be compatible with the bitmap that is currently selected – which, for a newly-created memory DC is a 1 x 1 *monochrome* bitmap.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap):

> Note: When a memory device context is created, it initially has a
> 1-by-1 monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device
> context is used in **CreateCompatibleBitmap**, the bitmap that is
> created is a *monochrome* bitmap. To create a color bitmap, use the
> **HDC** that was used to create the memory device context, as shown in the following code …